# How to modify APAcite style to list 1 author in the citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite

This is my first ever question here,

I'm trying to make some changes to APAcite style in order to be able to cite 1 author instead of a full list of authors:

For example, let's take this reference:

```
@article{WALKER2016713,
title = "Filling the observational void: Scientific value and quantitative validation of 
hydrometeorological data from a community-based monitoring programme",
journal = "Journal of Hydrology",
volume = "538",
pages = "713 - 725",
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jhydrol.2016.04.062},
year = "2016",
author = "David Walker and Nathan Forsythe and Geoff Parkin and John Gowing",}
```

When I cite it, the code yields: (Walker,Forsythe, Parkin, & Gowing, 2016), however, what I really want is (Walker et al., 2016), because there is no need for the full list of names in my work.

It's mentioned in the APAcite original code ([here](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.dtx)) that: 1 or 2 names: always cite all of them, and 3-5 names: cite all of them the first time, and only the first name later times. See that part of the code:

```
% Compute tentative number of names that must be cited (1).
% Call with
%   field  tentative.cite.num.names.field

FUNCTION {tentative.cite.num.names.field}
{ 'field :=
  field num.names$  'numnames :=
  numnames #3 <
    {   %
        % 1 or 2 names: always cite all of them.
      numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
      numnames  'cite.num.names.short :=
    }
    { numnames #6 <
        {   %
            % 3-5 names: cite all of them the first time,
            % only the first name later times
          numnames  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1        'cite.num.names.short :=
        }
        {   %
            % 6 or more names: cite only the first name
          #1  'cite.num.names.full  :=
          #1  'cite.num.names.short :=
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

I hope that there is a way to modify this specific detail in the code so I can cite the way I want.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `apacite` implements APA6, where this author-list expansion is required the first time an item is cited. You can still use `\shortcite` to get an abbreviated author citation: see the apacite package documentation http://texdoc.net/pkg/apacite, section on "Full and short author lists". If you're usint the `natbib` package option; then see the `\shortcites` command. But if you need to follow APA*7*, then it would be beset to use `biblatex` with `style=apa` instead...

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I checked the apacite documentation and the solution is indeed to use \shortcites, 
basically it's used this way with natbib: 
\shortcites{key}\citet{key} or \shortcites{key}\citep{key}

Problem solved :)